Does all my credits have to be from same degree when applying for masters?
I noticed many of the admissions requirements for masters in data science requires some credit on computer science. Currently I am doing a closed credit Bachelor's on Geology in a university where there is no course for programming. If I do a programming course from another university will it be considered as the required credit for those masters degrees?

One typically is required to submit transcripts from all prior educational endeavors. In this case, it will be clear to anyone deciding on your admission what you have taken and the associated grades.
The direct answer to the headline question is "no". But the quality of each program you have been part of might be considered. If the other university is reputable, then you should be ok, but the decisions are made by individuals.
And, of course, different universities have different rules.
